# Handling NSArray and NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm working with the MKMapView and I'm using some arrays to handle the title of points on the map

```
NSString *mapTitles = @"title1^^title2^^title3^^title4";//this data changes between views
NSArray * titlesArray = [mapTitles componentsSeparatedByString: @"^^"];
NSMutableArray * maptitle = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[titlesArray count]]; 
[maptitle addObjectsFromArray:titlesArray];
```

When a user navigates to another page I want to clear the NSMutableArray so that when they come back to the map I can refresh it with new data. However as the NSMutableArray is getting populated by an NSArray which I can't clear, how do I ensure that the NSMutableArray only gets populated by new data as opposed to something that the NSArray may have kept from the previous view?.

Is it simply a case of releasing the NSArray, for example in viewWillDisappear?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't just say `maptitle = nil;` ?

Comment: If I clear the mutable array, e.g. in viewWillDisappear, and then the user comes back to the page, if the NSArray hasn't autoreleased, it's still holding the data from the user's first visit, so it appears that the mutable array gets populated with old data + new data, rather than just the new data.

Comment: I don't think I understand how you are refreshing your data.  Where is the new data coming in?  If you making a new titlesArray each time then you will not have a problem.

Comment: Dancreek you're right. The problem was not with the NSArray, it was with the data I was feeding into it. It wasn't clearing out properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can still clear the mutable array itself:

```
[mapTitle removeAllObjects];
```

You shouldn't release the `titlesArray` because it's autoreleased.

Comment: Can I control when the autorelease takes place?

Comment: You could enclose it in a new autorelease pool (alloc/init a new one, do your autoreleased stuff then drain and release the pool), but you really shouldn't. It has nothing to do with your issue.